# How to delete a row with a condition in other table (sql)

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

```
CUSTOMER ( Cid, CName, City, Discount )
AGENT ( Aid, AName, City, Percent )  
PRODUCT ( Pid, PName, City, Quantity, Price )  
ORDERS ( OrderNo, Month, Cid, Aid, Pid, OrderedQuantity, Cost )
```

Q-
Delete all orders placed by agents living in New York city.

Comment: I'd strongly suggest reading the [Open letter to students with homework problems](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could use the `in` operator:

```
DELETE
FROM   orders
WHERE  aid IN (SELECT aid
               FROM   agent
               WHERE  city = 'New York')
```